# Zabbix - list of groups for host

Tags: zabbix

I'm trying to get list of groups of certain host from zabbix.

```
curl -X GET -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"hostgroup.get","params":{"output":"extend","filter":{"hostid":"10789"}},"id":1,"auth":"mytoken"}' http://zabbix-server/api_jsonrpc.php
```

But instead of three groups for this certain host, I get ALL groups on my zabbix server.

What should i change in my code?

Answer (score 0):

From the [API](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.4/manual/api/reference/host/get) documentation:

> Retrieve names of the groups host “Zabbix server” is member of, but no
>   host details themselves.
>
> Request:

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "host.get",
    "params": {
        "output": ["hostid"],
        "selectGroups": "extend",
        "filter": {
            "host": [
                "Zabbix server"
            ]
        }
    },
    "auth": "038e1d7b1735c6a5436ee9eae095879e",
    "id": 2
}
```

> Response:

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "result": [
        {
            "hostid": "10085",
            "groups": [
                {
                    "groupid": "2",
                    "name": "Linux servers",
                    "internal": "0",
                    "flags": "0"
                },
                {
                    "groupid": "4",
                    "name": "Zabbix servers",
                    "internal": "0",
                    "flags": "0"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "id": 2
}
```